# Why an explicit constructor is required before creating a copy constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor

I was trying to define a copy constructor in my example here. However, I found that the default/implicit constructor doesn't make compiler happy if the copy constructor has to be used. Why is it so? Is there any reason behind it?

```
class DemoCpyConstructor
{

private:

    int priv_var1;
    int priv_var2;

public:

    void setDemoCpyConstructor(int b1, int b2)
    {
        std::cout<<"The Demo Cpy Constructor Invoked"<<std::endl;
        priv_var1 = b1;
        priv_var2 = b2;

    }

    void showDemoCpyConstructor()
    {
        std::cout<<"The priv_var1 = "<<priv_var1<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"The priv_var2 = "<<priv_var2<<std::endl;
    }

    DemoCpyConstructor(const DemoCpyConstructor &oldObj)
    {
        std::cout<<"Copy Constructor Invoked.."<<std::endl;
        priv_var1 = oldObj.priv_var1;
        std::cout<<"Tweaking the copy constructor"<<std::endl;
        priv_var2 = 400;
    }


};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DemoCpyConstructor oldObj;
    oldObj.setDemoCpyConstructor(120,200);
    oldObj.showDemoCpyConstructor();

    DemoCpyConstructor newObj = oldObj;

    newObj.showDemoCpyConstructor();

    return 0;
}
```

This is what the error, I get -

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘DemoCpyConstructor::DemoCpyConstructor()’
```

Comment: You need one here: `DemoCpyConstructor oldObj;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you define any kind of constructor (means conversion, copy) and you want to use the default one as well you have to explicitly provide it. its the rule